# Using an IF-statement to define the Entry URL Format

Tags: url, conditional, entry-type

Within a channel I have two kinds of possible article types, which I separate with the entry type feature. For the entry URL format I want to include the type, but only for *one* of the two.

I've tried `channel{% if type.handle == 'xyz' %}/{type}{% endif %}/{slug}` but without success.

I've tested "if 2 > 1" and it *did* output the type, so I guess the structure of the if-statement is correct. Does anyone have an idea how I could make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, I was able to figure it out myself:

```
channel{% if object.type == 'xyz' %}/{type}{% endif %}/{slug}
```

produces the desired results. The section for [Dynamic Entry Titles](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#dynamic-entry-titles) in the docs pointed me into the right direction.