# Performance hit from Entry Url Format with multiple {% if %} clauses?

Tags: categories, url, conditional

With help from [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/using-an-if-statement-to-define-the-entry-url-format), I've got an Entry Url Format that can include top, 2nd, or 3rd-level categories.  It works for any of these situations:

```
top-level-category/entry.slug
top-level-category/second-level-category/entry.slug
top-level-category/second-level-category/third-level-category/entry.slug

{% if object.mainCategory.last().level == 3 %}{mainCategory.last().parent.parent.slug}/{% endif %}{% if object.mainCategory.last().level > 1 %}{mainCategory.last().parent.slug}/{% endif %}{mainCategory.last().slug}/{postDate.year}/{slug}
```

It's ugly, but it works. But I'm wondering if it is slowing things down a bit.  Does anyone have any knowledge in this area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as Craft is concerned whatever is in the `Entry URL Format` field is just another Twig snippet of code.  It gets rendered down super fast just like any other Twig code.  A few `if` conditionals aren't going to have any measurable impact on that process.

Comment: Thank you, Brad, that's good to know.  Also, [this answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/url-format-of-a-nested-structure-with-3-or-more-layers) showed me that the conditionals are unnecessary for this. `{mainCategory.last().uri}/{postDate.year}/{slug}` is all I need to be able to handle any level of nested categories.

Comment: Ahh, yeah... there's that, too. :)